# result set from self joined table and another one MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

DB: MySql
I have two tables - **Student** and **MoneyExchange**. Student has columns **StudentId**, **FirstName** and **LastName**. MoneyExchange has columns **StudentIDFrom**, **StudentIdTo** and **Amount**. This table will have the details of money exchanged between students. Both StudentIdFrom and StudentIDTo refers to the StudentId column in Student Table.
I would like to build a query that has the below result set:

StudentIdFrom,FirstNameFrom,LastNameFrom,StudentIdTo,FirstNameTo,LastNameTo,Amount (top 15 ascending order of Amount) .

Comment: tried various join/sub query options, but none retrieved my required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to alias the tables so that you can reference them both:

```
select
    money_ex.StudentIdFrom,
    st_from.FirstName,
    st_from.LastName,
    money_ex.StudentIdTo,
    st_to.FirstName,
    st_to.LastName,
    money_ex.Amount
from
    MoneyExchange as money_ex
    join Student as st_from on money_ex.StudentIdFrom = st_from.StudentId
    join Student as st_to on money_ex.StudentIdTo = st_to.StudentId
order by
    money_ex.Amount asc
limit 0 , 15;
```